# Returning only the highest value of a counter

Tags: arrays, processing

With the code below, I want to display the total number of 'num' in an array of 'phyScore'. At the moment, the code is display 1,2,3,4,5 on top of each other.

```
   int t = 0;
   int v = 0;
   for (float num : phyScore)
   {      
     if ((num >=71) && (num <=91))
     {
       t += num;
       v += 1;
       fill(0);
       textSize(10);
       text(v, 110, 15);
     }
   }
```

Please can you tell how I can display only the last element in v?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Tag says language is Processing

Comment: Processing is a type of Java language for visual arts. So the tag can include 'Java' too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the processing language, but it looks like you are repeatedly calling `text()` within your foreach loop.

Moving the `text(v, 110, 15);` outside your loop's body will execute it only once after the loop is completely finished.

```
for (float num : phyScore)
{      
     if ((num >=71) && (num <=91))
     {
         v += 1;
         //the rest of your code          
     }
}
text(v, 110, 15);
```